# Call to undefined method orderBy() (LARAVEL)

Tags: php, laravel, group-by, undefined

I want to sort descending, but i got to this error and i cant figure out what it is.. please help me

```
public function pedido_produtos() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\PedidoProduto')
                ->select(DB::raw('produto_id, sum(preco) as valores, count(1) as qtde')
                ->groupBy('produto_id')
                ->orderBy('produto_id', 'DESC'));
}
```

Comment: You placed extra ')' at the end.

Comment: yes, i just realized that, and i feel dumb now

Answer (score 0):

Its a typo at the end, remove one ')'

```
public function pedido_produtos() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\PedidoProduto')
                ->select(DB::raw('produto_id, sum(preco) as valores, count(1) as qtde')
                ->groupBy('produto_id')
                ->orderBy('produto_id', 'DESC');
}
```

Comment: This comment is a bit vague.  It would improve the quality of your answer if you put the changed code in your answer.

Comment: @NigelRen you can edit my answer, doesnt hurt nobody

Comment: The post was in the 'marked as a low-quality post' review queue.  It was a case of trying to improve the quality or recommending to delete it.  I prefer to give the benefit of the doubt first.

Comment: I see, thanks for the awareness! I wrote the answer from mobile thats why !

Answer (score 0):

Alter the query, Because the closing of the ")" is incorrect

```
return $this->hasMany('App\PedidoProduto')
                ->select(DB::raw('produto_id, sum(preco) as valores, count(1) as qtde'))
                ->groupBy('produto_id')
                ->orderBy('produto_id', 'DESC');
```